# How to add more_like_this query in elastic search using php

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am trying to include Elastic search into my application. In a scenario a user can select field type and enter the searchable value.

Let say, Search using First Name and Value is `'ABC'`.
I have tried this using bool query,but How i can use `'more_like_this'` query method?.
This what I have done so far.

```
$searchParams['index'] = 'articles';
$searchParams['type']  = 'article';
$searchParams['body']['query']['match']['body'] = 'ABC';
$queryResponse = $es->search($searchParams);
```

but if i put more_like_this into the query field,data cannot be selected.
any help please?
Thanks in advance

**This is the edited code**

```
$searchParams['index'] = 'articles';
$searchParams['type']  = 'article';

$searchParams['body']['query']['more_like_this']['fields'] = array('body','title');
$searchParams['body']['query']['more_like_this']['like_text'] =  $q;
$searchParams['body']['query']['more_like_this']['min_term_freq'] = 1;
$searchParams['body']['query']['more_like_this']['percent_terms_to_match'] = 1;
$searchParams['body']['query']['more_like_this']['min_doc_freq'] = 1;
```

Can you tell me what this lines for?

```
$searchParams['body']['query']['more_like_this']['min_term_freq'] = 1;
$searchParams['body']['query']['more_like_this']['percent_terms_to_match'] = 1;
$searchParams['body']['query']['more_like_this']['min_doc_freq'] = 1;
```

Comment: Here's a code sample: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/issues/57

Comment: @AndreiStefan:i think mlt is to get a single record.In this case i need the like query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an array, that will look like a json to ES:

```
{
   "query": {
      "more_like_this": {
         "fields": [
            "text"
         ],
         "like_text": "apple",
         "min_term_freq": 1,
         "percent_terms_to_match": 1,
         "min_doc_freq": 1
      }
   }
}
```

So in PHP it will be:

```
$searchParams['body']['query']['more_like_this']['fields'] = array('body');
$searchParams['body']['query']['more_like_this']['like_text'] = 'apple';
$searchParams['body']['query']['more_like_this']['min_term_freq'] = 1;
$searchParams['body']['query']['more_like_this']['percent_terms_to_match'] = 1;
$searchParams['body']['query']['more_like_this']['min_doc_freq'] = 1;
```

Comment: :i just tried it and it works,but i have a problem.let say i have added another field called 'title'.I am searching word called 'Excep' in Body tag.but i couldn't get the correct answer.
I have edited my code above